# How to include inline .svg in Nuxt application

Tags: html, vue.js, svg, webpack, nuxt.js

I want to do a common thing - include dynamically an svg HTML in Vue Nuxt application which I will able to style. To do this, I created a component but instead of image, I get a text *data:image/svg+xhtml...*.

How to make it work?

```
<template>
   <div v-html="src"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Icon',
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        src() {
            const src = require(`assets/icons/${this.name}.svg`)
            return src
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

It seems like [`@nuxtjs/svg`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-module) will do what you're trying to do. After installing it, try:

```
<template>
   <div v-html="src"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Icon',
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        src() {
            const src = require(`assets/icons/${this.name}.svg?raw`)
            return src
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nice. I was trying to do it in a straight Vue project. That Nuxt plugin is a much better solution.

Comment: @laptou I have now text /_nuxt/5476b1293b10e0056bf8a8f9cf8c93c4.svg
instead of image

Comment: I had the same issue and replaced the `<div v-html="src"></div>` with `<component v-bind:is="src"></component>`. Also the src computed property can return this `return require(\`assets/icons/${this.name}.svg?inline\`).default`

Comment: upvoted what if all your svg files are inside node_modules folder

Comment: @PirateApp why would you put SVG files in the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @laptou not me but I library I am trying to use has its svg icons inside node_modules after installing it and i was wondering how to use it

Comment: requiring inside the computed func drops a compiler error !
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~assets/img in component ...

Answer (score 1):

try doing this, watch out for the **"/_nuxt/assets"** extension.

```
       <td v-if="actions" class="px-4 flex flex-row py-2 justify-end">
          <span v-for="action in actions" :key="action.key">
            <NuxtLink :to="action.to + '/' + item['actions']">
              <a>
                <img class="pl-2 pr-2" 
       :src="`/_nuxt/assets/images/dataTableIcons/${action.value}.svg`"
                  :alt="action.value">
              </a>
            </NuxtLink>
          </span>
        </td>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not easy and I tried a bunch of different solutions that "seemed" like they should work.

My understanding is that it comes down to how Webpack deals with "image" assets and using them inline vs stand-alone sort of changes the definition.

I've got a library of SVG icons that needed code access (eg change colors after run time) so I had to have the SVG inline. Here's where I landed, It's not ideal but it works.

---

Create a new component with a prop slot for SVG name. Inside that component add all your svg's as code. Wrap each in a v-if.

```html
<template>
   <div class="svgIcon">
      <svg v-if="icon == 'name1'">...</svg>
      <svg v-if="icon == 'name2'">...</svg>
      <svg v-if="icon == 'name3'">...</svg>
      <svg v-if="icon == 'name4'">...</svg>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['icon']
  }
</script>
```

Then use the component by filling the name you want in the slot

```html
<template>
   <div>
      <svgIcons :icon="name1"></svgIcons>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  import svgIcons from '../path/to/iconsComponent.vue'
  export default {
    components: { svgIcons },
    ...
  }
</script>
```