# SVG doesn't render using @nuxtjs/svg

Tags: svg, nuxt.js

Using "vue-svg-loader" method to the letter in [the module's docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/svg#vue-svg-loader), I get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid Component definition:
> data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0...

My code is identical to the example.

Any idea why I'm getting such error?

(note that previously I tried to use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044628/871404) and didn't get error, however a string "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTMiIGhl..." was rendered on the page instead of the actual SVG image)

EDIT: below is my template's code, in `/components/global/SvgIcon.vue`.

```
<template>
  <ArrowRight />
</template>

<script>
import ArrowRight from '~/assets/img/arrow-right.svg?inline'

export default {
  components: {
    ArrowRight
  }
}
</script>
```

And my SVG icon is in `/assets/img/`.

SVG file content:

```
<svg width="13" height="20" viewBox="0 0 13 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M12.3604 9.93625C12.3604 10.2924 12.2231 10.6485 11.9492 10.9201L3.32384 19.4648C2.77517 20.0083 1.88558 20.0083 1.33712 19.4648C0.788667 18.9214 0.788667 18.0403 1.33712 17.4967L8.96929 9.93625L1.33739 2.37573C0.788933 1.83218 0.788933 0.951159 1.33739 0.407866C1.88585 -0.135954 2.77543 -0.135954 3.32411 0.407865L11.9494 8.95245C12.2234 9.22412 12.3604 9.58023 12.3604 9.93625Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your `nuxt.config.js` config file and add a reference to module `@nuxtjs/svg`
(as described in the Installation section in [the module's doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/svg#installation))

I've tested it by on a [minimal project](https://github.com/MilosCernak/nuxtjs-svg-example) (nuxt hello world example + @nuxtjs/svg). Initially it worked ok and rendered the image correctly. After removing the module reference, I got the same error message as you've described.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I had forgotten that! But now instead of seeing the SVG image I see it's file name rendered in the DOM: `/_nuxt/fce91b3f7439fe8fc414930e5cd5b231.svg`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behaviour that you've described, so I've posted the minimal example on GitHub (link added to answer). See if it helps or otherwise add a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Dunno what I did, but it works now. Thanks a lot :)