# How to add inline SVGs in a nuxt3 vite project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, vite, nuxtjs3

Hi have been having troubling importing inline svgs into my nuxt3 vite project. Any advice would be much appreciated.

i found this works  `<img src="~/assets/images/icons/push-icon-chatops.svg" />` however i need an inline item.   so i would do something like this `<div v-html="rawNuxtLogo" />` and doing something like this(require doesnt work in vite) .

```
setup(props) {
        const currentIcon = computed(() => {
            return defineAsyncComponent(() =>
                import(`~/assets/images/icons/push-icon-chatops.svg'?inline`)
            );
        }).value;

        return {
            currentIcon,
        };
    },
```

however i found that vite does imports weirdly and the result is either the url string showing in the v-html or a object that doesnt read

i am trying to use this plugin with no success.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include inline .svg in Nuxt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043904/how-to-include-inline-svg-in-nuxt-application)

Comment: @bitski so that was one of the items i looked at.   require doesnt work in vite so i had to do that dynamic import bit,  however it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so its seems that vite is actually not compatiable with the `@nuxtjs/svg` plugin.      so the answer is to rather install a vite specific plugin in this case i installed [vite plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader) then do this

```
vite: {
    plugins: [
        svgLoader()
    ]
},
```

Comment: Could have given a try to [nuxt-svgo](https://github.com/cpsoinos/nuxt-svgo) but overall, a Vite plugin is also what I achieved for a friend few months ago and it works great! Please accept your answer when you will be able to.

Answer (score 2):

For TS Nuxt 3 projects it would be like this.

`nuxt.config.ts` file:

```
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // Rest of your config.
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      svgLoader({
       // Your settings.
      }),
    ],
  },
})
```

Example for a component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ArrowLeft />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import ArrowLeft from '../assets/svg/arrow-left.svg?component'
</script>
```

Note that the `?component` in the end is important, otherwise TS will complain.

Plugin Documentation: [vite-svg-loader](https://github.com/jpkleemans/vite-svg-loader#readme)

Comment: how change size when using this?

Comment: @AlauddinAfifCassandra - if you mean the actual size of the SVG on the screen, that is done in the HTML/CSS. This answer only has to do with how you load the SVG file.

Comment: How would this work for dynamic imports? I have 
`<component :is="icon" />` in template and then 
`icon.value = import(\`~/assets/icons/${props.name}.svg\`)` and I am getting ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '~/assets/icons/arrow-up.svg'```

Answer (score 1):

Inline Svg images in nuxt 3, without using any library, such as `vite-svg-loader` or `nuxt-svgo`.

```js
    <template>
        <span v-html="icon" />
    </template>

    <script lang="ts" setup>
       import { filename } from 'pathe/utils';
      
       const props = defineProps<{
            icon: string;
        }>();
    
       // Auto-load icons as raw
       const glob = import.meta.glob('~/assets/*.svg', { as: 'raw' });
       const images = Object.fromEntries(
       Object.entries(glob)
         .map(([key, value]: [string, any]) => [filename(key), value]))
    
       // Lazily load the icon
       const icon = props.icon && (await images?.[props.icon]?.());
    </script>
```

Comment: it's always advisable to put the actual content, instead of a link to the answers(s). A link might not exist sin future.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me to import it dynamically, using vite-svg-loader:

```
<template>
  <component :is="icon" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: 'logo'
  }
})

const icons = import.meta.glob(`@/**/*.svg`)

const icon = computed(() => {
  return defineAsyncComponent(() => {
    return icons[`/assets/images/icons/${props.name}.svg`]()
  })
})

</script>
```